# Creating Android Library Project: R.id

Tags: android, android-library

I'm creating an Android Library Project, and I have a class in which the programmer has to pass an `R.layout.some_layout`, to the instance, in which some view should have an `@+id/text`

So the idea is that I create an XML layout file, I add a view with an "text" as its ID, and after I instantiate the class I use `object.setLayout(R.layout.some_layout);`

In the definition of the class there is something like this:

```
public void setLayout(int layoutId) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.text); // error here cause of the R.id
}
```

The problem is that since it's a library project, my `R.java` doesn't have an `R.id`, so it marks an error on that line. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in one of your **xml** file

Kindly check your xml may be some syntax error remain with the xml file which is preventing to create complete R.java

Then

**Clean & Rebuild** your project and also you can **Restart IDE** if problem remains

[image]

Comment: I currently don't have any XML file, as I said I'm building a library.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco then skip checking clean rebuild restart

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your `R.java` file was generated correctly? If not, please clean build your library project and check again.